# When Windows Update displays the prompt to reboot to finish installing an update, why does TrustedInstaller continue to use RAM/CPU resources?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When automatic updates have been enabled from within Windows 7 and Windows Update prompts that the machine needs to be restarted to install the update, I've noticed that the "TrustedInstaller.exe" process is always using hundreds of megabytes of RAM and lots of CPU. Why does TrustedInstaller continue to use resources until the machine is restarted - why is it not killed when the prompt to reboot is displayed?

Comment: Generally when reboot after update needed, some operations before shutdown must be performed, and some of them does not need in single mode.

Comment: This makes sense - however, upon activating the "Restart" button, the machine immediatley restarts which would suggest that whatever actions being carried out by TrustedInstaller at the time wern't actually needed for a successful reboot.

Comment: Trusted Installer if performing all kinds of cleanup tasks after updates are installed, which can be interrupted by a restart, it will just finish on the next startup.